# why does my aws dynamodb TTL keep fire off phantom INSERT and REMOVE event even when there is no item in the table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, ttl

I'm doing a project using dynamoDB TTL feature to do scheduled tasks. the scheme came most from this article series:
https://theburningmonk.com/2019/03/dynamodb-ttl-as-an-ad-hoc-scheduling-mechanism/ 
So I created a dynamoDB table called "scheduledTasks" , and a lambda function called "stepScheduler" which will be triggered by dynamoDB stream events.
In any case, during testing my lambda functions, I made some mistake on my client-side (in this case, 
android java app) code, so to clean things up, I deleted all entries in my dynamoDB table, but I noticed from my cloudwatch logs that even when my dynamoDB table is empty, the dynamoDB stream is constantly firing off INSERT and REMOVE events at nearly once per minute rate. There are just phantom events since I have zero items in my dynamoDB table. Any help on pinpointing why this is happening is greatly appreciated!.

Sam

## The following is an excerpt of my cloudwatch logs:

2020-06-08T18:02:26.713-07:00
START RequestId: 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 Version: $LATEST

2020-06-08T18:02:26.719-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:26.719Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO Processing event record:{"Records":[{"eventID":"a0ac4e41f30757c71a83da2e54578d85","eventName":"INSERT","eventVersion":"1.1","eventSource":"aws:dynamodb","awsRegion":"us-east-1","dynamodb":{"ApproximateCreationDateTime":1591650485,"Keys":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591650600"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00"}},"NewImage":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591650600"},"waitTime":{"N":"60"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00"}},"SequenceNumber":"337634800000000013869836359","SizeBytes":160,"StreamViewType":"NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"},"eventSourceARN":"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133"}]}

2020-06-08T18:02:26.719-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:26.719Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO Record[0]

2020-06-08T18:02:26.719-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:26.719Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO { "eventID": "a0ac4e41f30757c71a83da2e54578d85", "eventName": "INSERT", "eventVersion": "1.1", "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb", "awsRegion": "us-east-1", "dynamodb": { "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1591650485, "Keys": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591650600" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00" } }, "NewImage": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591650600" }, "waitTime": { "N": "60" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00" } }, "SequenceNumber": "337634800000000013869836359", "SizeBytes": 160, "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES" }, "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133" }

2020-06-08T18:02:26.720-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:26.720Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO Device ID [LEDSCE50E365802D] Schedule ID [2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00] !!!LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00::60

2020-06-08T18:02:27.139-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:27.101Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO now fire off all promises.....(1)

2020-06-08T18:02:27.379-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:27.341Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO started execution of step function

2020-06-08T18:02:27.380-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:27.380Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO stepFunctionRecords.....{"executionArn":"arn:aws:states:us-east-1:667118410653:execution:schedule1Wait:5e8a5ddc-e89a-496e-8e6e-c8cffd0c57a3","startDate":"2020-06-09T01:02:27.297Z","deviceId":"LEDSCE50E365802D","scheduleId":"2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00"}

2020-06-08T18:02:27.380-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:27.380Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO Updating ARN!!!!!!arn:aws:states:us-east-1:667118410653:execution:schedule1Wait:5e8a5ddc-e89a-496e-8e6e-c8cffd0c57a3

2020-06-08T18:02:27.539-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:27.521Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 ERROR Unhandled Promise Rejection {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: Unknown device","reason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Unknown device","stack":["Error: Unknown device"," at Object. (/var/task/index.js:24:24)"," at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)"," at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)"," at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)"," at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)"," at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)"," at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)"," at _tryRequire (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:75:12)"," at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:95:12)"," at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: Unknown device"," at process. (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)"," at process.emit (events.js:310:20)"," at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)"," at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)"," at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"]}

2020-06-08T18:02:27.632-07:00
END RequestId: 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548

2020-06-08T18:02:27.632-07:00
REPORT RequestId: 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 Duration: 918.37 ms Billed Duration: 1000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 84 MB Init Duration: 369.88 ms

2020-06-08T18:02:27.632-07:00
Unknown application error occurred

2020-06-08T18:02:36.401-07:00
START RequestId: a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 Version: $LATEST

2020-06-08T18:02:36.419-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:36.406Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO Processing event record:{"Records":[{"eventID":"97fe4d3c2a9dde81a2768c3ef2c3565e","eventName":"INSERT","eventVersion":"1.1","eventSource":"aws:dynamodb","awsRegion":"us-east-1","dynamodb":{"ApproximateCreationDateTime":1591650051,"Keys":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591650180"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00"}},"NewImage":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591650180"},"waitTime":{"N":"60"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00"}},"SequenceNumber":"337599100000000021853375173","SizeBytes":162,"StreamViewType":"NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"},"eventSourceARN":"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133"}]}

2020-06-08T18:02:36.419-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:36.419Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO Record[0]

2020-06-08T18:02:36.419-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:36.419Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO { "eventID": "97fe4d3c2a9dde81a2768c3ef2c3565e", "eventName": "INSERT", "eventVersion": "1.1", "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb", "awsRegion": "us-east-1", "dynamodb": { "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1591650051, "Keys": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591650180" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00" } }, "NewImage": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591650180" }, "waitTime": { "N": "60" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00" } }, "SequenceNumber": "337599100000000021853375173", "SizeBytes": 162, "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES" }, "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133" }

2020-06-08T18:02:36.419-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:36.419Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO Device ID [LEDSCE50E365802D] Schedule ID [2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00] !!!LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00::60

2020-06-08T18:02:36.761-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:36.761Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO now fire off all promises.....(1)

2020-06-08T18:02:37.260-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:37.260Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO started execution of step function

2020-06-08T18:02:37.262-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:37.262Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO stepFunctionRecords.....{"executionArn":"arn:aws:states:us-east-1:667118410653:execution:schedule1Wait:141cad07-8f1f-4e5d-8dd0-c4eda3762f69","startDate":"2020-06-09T01:02:37.189Z","deviceId":"LEDSCE50E365802D","scheduleId":"2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00"}

2020-06-08T18:02:37.262-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:37.262Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO Updating ARN!!!!!!arn:aws:states:us-east-1:667118410653:execution:schedule1Wait:141cad07-8f1f-4e5d-8dd0-c4eda3762f69

2020-06-08T18:02:37.421-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:37.421Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 ERROR Unhandled Promise Rejection {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: Unknown device","reason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Unknown device","stack":["Error: Unknown device"," at Object. (/var/task/index.js:24:24)"," at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)"," at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)"," at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)"," at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)"," at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)"," at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)"," at _tryRequire (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:75:12)"," at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:95:12)"," at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: Unknown device"," at process. (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)"," at process.emit (events.js:310:20)"," at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)"," at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)"," at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"]}

2020-06-08T18:02:37.516-07:00
END RequestId: a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2

2020-06-08T18:02:37.516-07:00
REPORT RequestId: a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 Duration: 1111.23 ms Billed Duration: 1200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 25 MB

2020-06-08T18:02:37.516-07:00
Unknown application error occurred

2020-06-08T18:02:46.279-07:00
START RequestId: 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 Version: $LATEST

2020-06-08T18:02:46.286-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:46.286Z 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 INFO Processing event record:{"Records":[{"eventID":"73829573226ef3e502cd9c976f0c1ae8","eventName":"REMOVE","eventVersion":"1.1","eventSource":"aws:dynamodb","awsRegion":"us-east-1","dynamodb":{"ApproximateCreationDateTime":1591588854,"Keys":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591553340"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-07T10:52:43.159-07:00"}},"OldImage":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591553340"},"waitTime":{"N":"60"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-07T10:52:43.159-07:00"}},"SequenceNumber":"334489900000000017308621764","SizeBytes":162,"StreamViewType":"NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"},"eventSourceARN":"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133"}]}

2020-06-08T18:02:46.299-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:46.286Z 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 INFO Record[0]

2020-06-08T18:02:46.299-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:46.299Z 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 INFO { "eventID": "73829573226ef3e502cd9c976f0c1ae8", "eventName": "REMOVE", "eventVersion": "1.1", "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb", "awsRegion": "us-east-1", "dynamodb": { "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1591588854, "Keys": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591553340" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-07T10:52:43.159-07:00" } }, "OldImage": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591553340" }, "waitTime": { "N": "60" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-07T10:52:43.159-07:00" } }, "SequenceNumber": "334489900000000017308621764", "SizeBytes": 162, "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES" }, "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133" }

2020-06-08T18:02:46.299-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:46.299Z 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 INFO now fire off all promises.....(0)

2020-06-08T18:02:49.287-07:00
END RequestId: 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53

2020-06-08T18:02:49.287-07:00
REPORT RequestId: 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 Duration: 3003.23 ms Billed Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 23 MB

2020-06-08T18:02:49.287-07:00
2020-06-09T01:02:49.287Z 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

2020-06-08T18:03:31.070-07:00
START RequestId: 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 Version: $LATEST

2020-06-08T18:03:31.074-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:31.074Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO Processing event record:{"Records":[{"eventID":"a0ac4e41f30757c71a83da2e54578d85","eventName":"INSERT","eventVersion":"1.1","eventSource":"aws:dynamodb","awsRegion":"us-east-1","dynamodb":{"ApproximateCreationDateTime":1591650485,"Keys":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591650600"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00"}},"NewImage":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591650600"},"waitTime":{"N":"60"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00"}},"SequenceNumber":"337634800000000013869836359","SizeBytes":160,"StreamViewType":"NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"},"eventSourceARN":"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133"}]}

2020-06-08T18:03:31.083-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:31.079Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO Record[0]

2020-06-08T18:03:31.083-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:31.079Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO { "eventID": "a0ac4e41f30757c71a83da2e54578d85", "eventName": "INSERT", "eventVersion": "1.1", "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb", "awsRegion": "us-east-1", "dynamodb": { "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1591650485, "Keys": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591650600" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00" } }, "NewImage": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591650600" }, "waitTime": { "N": "60" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00" } }, "SequenceNumber": "337634800000000013869836359", "SizeBytes": 160, "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES" }, "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133" }

2020-06-08T18:03:31.083-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:31.079Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO Device ID [LEDSCE50E365802D] Schedule ID [2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00] !!!LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00::60

2020-06-08T18:03:31.421-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:31.421Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO now fire off all promises.....(1)

2020-06-08T18:03:31.859-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:31.859Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO started execution of step function

2020-06-08T18:03:31.901-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:31.900Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO stepFunctionRecords.....{"executionArn":"arn:aws:states:us-east-1:667118410653:execution:schedule1Wait:78a339f4-c432-440d-bd66-f277b5641889","startDate":"2020-06-09T01:03:31.826Z","deviceId":"LEDSCE50E365802D","scheduleId":"2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00"}

2020-06-08T18:03:31.901-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:31.900Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO Updating ARN!!!!!!arn:aws:states:us-east-1:667118410653:execution:schedule1Wait:78a339f4-c432-440d-bd66-f277b5641889

2020-06-08T18:03:32.059-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:32.040Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 ERROR Unhandled Promise Rejection {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: Unknown device","reason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Unknown device","stack":["Error: Unknown device"," at Object. (/var/task/index.js:24:24)"," at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)"," at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)"," at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)"," at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)"," at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)"," at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)"," at _tryRequire (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:75:12)"," at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:95:12)"," at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: Unknown device"," at process. (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)"," at process.emit (events.js:310:20)"," at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)"," at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)"," at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"]}

2020-06-08T18:03:32.132-07:00
END RequestId: 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548

2020-06-08T18:03:32.132-07:00
REPORT RequestId: 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 Duration: 1059.92 ms Billed Duration: 1100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 24 MB

2020-06-08T18:03:32.132-07:00
Unknown application error occurred

2020-06-08T18:03:48.780-07:00
START RequestId: a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 Version: $LATEST

2020-06-08T18:03:48.785-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:48.785Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO Processing event record:{"Records":[{"eventID":"97fe4d3c2a9dde81a2768c3ef2c3565e","eventName":"INSERT","eventVersion":"1.1","eventSource":"aws:dynamodb","awsRegion":"us-east-1","dynamodb":{"ApproximateCreationDateTime":1591650051,"Keys":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591650180"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00"}},"NewImage":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591650180"},"waitTime":{"N":"60"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00"}},"SequenceNumber":"337599100000000021853375173","SizeBytes":162,"StreamViewType":"NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"},"eventSourceARN":"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133"}]}

2020-06-08T18:03:48.785-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:48.785Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO Record[0]

2020-06-08T18:03:48.785-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:48.785Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO { "eventID": "97fe4d3c2a9dde81a2768c3ef2c3565e", "eventName": "INSERT", "eventVersion": "1.1", "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb", "awsRegion": "us-east-1", "dynamodb": { "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1591650051, "Keys": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591650180" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00" } }, "NewImage": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591650180" }, "waitTime": { "N": "60" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00" } }, "SequenceNumber": "337599100000000021853375173", "SizeBytes": 162, "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES" }, "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133" }

2020-06-08T18:03:48.785-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:48.785Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO Device ID [LEDSCE50E365802D] Schedule ID [2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00] !!!LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00::60

2020-06-08T18:03:49.140-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:49.140Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO now fire off all promises.....(1)

2020-06-08T18:03:49.639-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:49.621Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO started execution of step function

2020-06-08T18:03:49.641-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:49.641Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO stepFunctionRecords.....{"executionArn":"arn:aws:states:us-east-1:667118410653:execution:schedule1Wait:d598bec6-c2f6-432a-bff1-76b912ee5584","startDate":"2020-06-09T01:03:49.560Z","deviceId":"LEDSCE50E365802D","scheduleId":"2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00"}

2020-06-08T18:03:49.659-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:49.659Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO Updating ARN!!!!!!arn:aws:states:us-east-1:667118410653:execution:schedule1Wait:d598bec6-c2f6-432a-bff1-76b912ee5584

2020-06-08T18:03:49.781-07:00
2020-06-09T01:03:49.780Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 ERROR Unhandled Promise Rejection {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: Unknown device","reason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Unknown device","stack":["Error: Unknown device"," at Object. (/var/task/index.js:24:24)"," at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)"," at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)"," at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)"," at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)"," at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)"," at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)"," at _tryRequire (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:75:12)"," at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:95:12)"," at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: Unknown device"," at process. (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)"," at process.emit (events.js:310:20)"," at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)"," at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)"," at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"]}

2020-06-08T18:03:49.932-07:00
END RequestId: a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2

2020-06-08T18:03:49.932-07:00
REPORT RequestId: a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 Duration: 1149.26 ms Billed Duration: 1200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 24 MB

2020-06-08T18:03:49.932-07:00
Unknown application error occurred

2020-06-08T18:10:30.126-07:00
START RequestId: 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 Version: $LATEST

2020-06-08T18:10:30.131-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:30.131Z 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 INFO Processing event record:{"Records":[{"eventID":"73829573226ef3e502cd9c976f0c1ae8","eventName":"REMOVE","eventVersion":"1.1","eventSource":"aws:dynamodb","awsRegion":"us-east-1","dynamodb":{"ApproximateCreationDateTime":1591588854,"Keys":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591553340"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-07T10:52:43.159-07:00"}},"OldImage":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591553340"},"waitTime":{"N":"60"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-07T10:52:43.159-07:00"}},"SequenceNumber":"334489900000000017308621764","SizeBytes":162,"StreamViewType":"NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"},"eventSourceARN":"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133"}]}

2020-06-08T18:10:30.131-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:30.131Z 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 INFO Record[0]

2020-06-08T18:10:30.131-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:30.131Z 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 INFO { "eventID": "73829573226ef3e502cd9c976f0c1ae8", "eventName": "REMOVE", "eventVersion": "1.1", "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb", "awsRegion": "us-east-1", "dynamodb": { "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1591588854, "Keys": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591553340" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-07T10:52:43.159-07:00" } }, "OldImage": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591553340" }, "waitTime": { "N": "60" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-07T10:52:43.159-07:00" } }, "SequenceNumber": "334489900000000017308621764", "SizeBytes": 162, "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES" }, "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133" }

2020-06-08T18:10:30.131-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:30.131Z 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 INFO now fire off all promises.....(0)

2020-06-08T18:10:33.133-07:00
END RequestId: 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53

2020-06-08T18:10:33.133-07:00
REPORT RequestId: 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 Duration: 3003.37 ms Billed Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 25 MB

2020-06-08T18:10:33.133-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:33.132Z 9be00725-ce4c-4388-a39d-b4ef08ce2e53 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

2020-06-08T18:10:52.520-07:00
START RequestId: a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 Version: $LATEST

2020-06-08T18:10:52.526-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:52.525Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO Processing event record:{"Records":[{"eventID":"97fe4d3c2a9dde81a2768c3ef2c3565e","eventName":"INSERT","eventVersion":"1.1","eventSource":"aws:dynamodb","awsRegion":"us-east-1","dynamodb":{"ApproximateCreationDateTime":1591650051,"Keys":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591650180"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00"}},"NewImage":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591650180"},"waitTime":{"N":"60"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00"}},"SequenceNumber":"337599100000000021853375173","SizeBytes":162,"StreamViewType":"NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"},"eventSourceARN":"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133"}]}

2020-06-08T18:10:52.526-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:52.526Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO Record[0]

2020-06-08T18:10:52.526-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:52.526Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO { "eventID": "97fe4d3c2a9dde81a2768c3ef2c3565e", "eventName": "INSERT", "eventVersion": "1.1", "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb", "awsRegion": "us-east-1", "dynamodb": { "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1591650051, "Keys": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591650180" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00" } }, "NewImage": { "expirationTime": { "N": "1591650180" }, "waitTime": { "N": "60" }, "scheduleId": { "S": "LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00" } }, "SequenceNumber": "337599100000000021853375173", "SizeBytes": 162, "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES" }, "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133" }

2020-06-08T18:10:52.526-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:52.526Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO Device ID [LEDSCE50E365802D] Schedule ID [2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00] !!!LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00::60

2020-06-08T18:10:52.883-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:52.883Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO now fire off all promises.....(1)

2020-06-08T18:10:53.421-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:53.383Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO started execution of step function

2020-06-08T18:10:53.423-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:53.422Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO stepFunctionRecords.....{"executionArn":"arn:aws:states:us-east-1:667118410653:execution:schedule1Wait:34623f63-4b9c-4e5e-93d4-90647207a9de","startDate":"2020-06-09T01:10:53.329Z","deviceId":"LEDSCE50E365802D","scheduleId":"2020-06-08T14:00:05.380-07:00"}

2020-06-08T18:10:53.423-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:53.423Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 INFO Updating ARN!!!!!!arn:aws:states:us-east-1:667118410653:execution:schedule1Wait:34623f63-4b9c-4e5e-93d4-90647207a9de

2020-06-08T18:10:53.582-07:00
2020-06-09T01:10:53.582Z a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 ERROR Unhandled Promise Rejection {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: Unknown device","reason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Unknown device","stack":["Error: Unknown device"," at Object. (/var/task/index.js:24:24)"," at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)"," at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)"," at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)"," at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)"," at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)"," at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)"," at _tryRequire (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:75:12)"," at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:95:12)"," at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: Unknown device"," at process. (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)"," at process.emit (events.js:310:20)"," at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)"," at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)"," at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"]}

2020-06-08T18:10:53.658-07:00
END RequestId: a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2

2020-06-08T18:10:53.658-07:00
REPORT RequestId: a2abb12c-9b9d-4e33-b2c9-752a368807c2 Duration: 1134.07 ms Billed Duration: 1200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 24 MB

2020-06-08T18:10:53.658-07:00
Unknown application error occurred

2020-06-08T18:11:22.472-07:00
START RequestId: 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 Version: $LATEST

2020-06-08T18:11:22.479-07:00
2020-06-09T01:11:22.478Z 6b87b475-110f-4805-9d76-43bffc1cf548 INFO Processing event record:{"Records":[{"eventID":"a0ac4e41f30757c71a83da2e54578d85","eventName":"INSERT","eventVersion":"1.1","eventSource":"aws:dynamodb","awsRegion":"us-east-1","dynamodb":{"ApproximateCreationDateTime":1591650485,"Keys":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591650600"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00"}},"NewImage":{"expirationTime":{"N":"1591650600"},"waitTime":{"N":"60"},"scheduleId":{"S":"LEDSCE50E365802D_2020-06-08T14:06:51.821-07:00"}},"SequenceNumber":"337634800000000013869836359","SizeBytes":160,"StreamViewType":"NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"},"eventSourceARN":"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:667118410653:table/scheduledTasks/stream/2020-06-08T03:58:27.133"}]}

================================================================================================

Answer (score 0):

OK, I realized the this is caused by re-try settings of the dynamodb-lambda trigger. when something is wrong with the lambda, the automatic re-try kicks in. I have it set up as 10000 times in the default.